# Unix/Linux: Sorting by numbers after a comma

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I am not very experienced with Linux/Unix, and I have a data file, with each line following the syntax of

```
[name of a crime that was committed],[numberOfOccurences]
```

For example, here are some of the lines of the file:

```
Partial 311,2
Carjacking Att,1
Rtr,1
Loiters,4
459 Susp Poss,2
Boat,6
Dog Attack,10
```

I want to sort the file in descending order by the numbers that follow the comma. I do not know the number of digits that follow the comma. I know I will use the "sort" command, with -r for descending order, but can somebody tell me the exact command to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To sort in descending order: `sort -t, -k2,2rn input-file`

The `-t,` tells sort that fields are separated by commas.
The `-k2,2` tell sort to sort starting at field 2 and ending at field 2.
The `-r` reverses the order for that sort key, and the `-n` tells sort that the field is to be ordered numerically (as opposed to lexicographically)